# React Router Infinite route loop with Redirect

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-router-dom

I have an authorized route that shouldn't let the user access the protected route without login.
However, when I'm using the Redirect after user is authenticated in context, the infinite loop between login and admin occurs. Simply the link changes from `login` to `admin` all the time.

Error

```sh
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Authorized Route

```js
const { user } = useAuthState();
  console.log('user in Authrized route', user);
  if (user) {
    return <Route {...props} />;
  }

return <Redirect to={ROUTES.LOGIN} />;
```

Redirect in Login component

```js
if (isAuthorized) {
    return <Redirect to="/admin" />
}
```

AuthController with context

```js
export const AuthController = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
    isAuthorized: false,
    isAuthorizing: false,
    user: undefined,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      dispatch(setAuthorized(user as any));
    })
  }, [state.isAuthorizing])

  if(state.isAuthorizing) {
    return <Spinner />
  }

  return <AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
    <AuthStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      {children}
    </AuthStateContext.Provider>
  </AuthDispatchContext.Provider>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, there is a path that requires to be logged in and an authorization.

- If not logged -> redirects to ROUTES.LOGIN.
- If it is logged and has authorization  -> serve content.
- **If it is logged and does not have authorization -> 401**

For the third case you should return a 404 Not Found or 401 Unauthorized response. With this logic there should not be any loop.